# Can I output JSON where the ID is the key rather than it being an array in ASP.NET MVC (C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So in ASP.NET MVC I have a Controller action somewhat like this:

```
public JsonResult People()
{
    var people = db.People.ToList();
    return Json(people);
}
```

and when ajaxed this will return something like this:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "John Smith"
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "Daryl Jackson"
  }
]
```

However, what I'm looking for is not a JSON array of the records as shown above, but more a JSON object where the IDs of each record is the key and then the record nested as the value, like so:

```
{
  1: {
    "Name": "John Smith"
  },
  2: {
    "Name": "Daryl Jackson"
  }
}
```

My initial thought would be to create a Dictionary in C# similar to this structure and pass it into Json() however the method does not know how to handle Dictionary objects.

Is there a way to achieve this kind of structure in C#? Currently I'm having to resort to restructuring it on the client-side or using loops to find a record with the ID I'm searching for. It'd be nicer if I could just get the record by ID in Javascript. Am I going about this all wrong? I'm new to the ASP.NET MVC environment.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: If you are passing this to javascript...it is generally easier to work with the array structure you currently have. But it does depend a bit on use case. Keep in mind that javascript arrays are sortable and easy to filter and javascript objects do not have controllable order

Comment: Does this work for you? "return Json(people.ToDictionary(x => x.ID.ToString(), x => new { x.Name }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);" This is assuming your person object consists of an int ID and string Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ToDictionary()` extension method.

```
public ActionResult People()
{
   var peopleDictionary = db.People
                          .Select(x=> new {  Id = x.Id, Name= x.FirstName})
                          .ToDictionary(d => d.Id.ToString(), p => p);

   return Json(peopleDictionary, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Assuming your People table has an `Id` and `FirstName` column, this code will return a json dictionary like this from your  table data

```
{ "101" : {"Id":101,"Name":"John"},"102":{"Id":102,"Name":"Darryl"} }
```

*Using the `Json` metod, You cannot serialize a dictionary where the dictionary key is of type int, so you need to explicitly convert your int value to a string.*

If you want to get a specific user from the a userId, you can use the dictionary style  syntax `yourJsObject[key]`

```
 var url="PutRelativeUrlToReportScoreHere";
 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //Get the User with Key 102
        console.log(data[102]);
 });
```

Comment: Or just people.ToDictionary(x => x.ID.ToString(), x => new { x.Name }).

Comment: I don't know how OP's entities/relationships are. So I added the `select` to prevent the possible Circular reference serialization errors.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Either way, using "p => new { p.Name }" would get your result closer to the OP's original needs.  This would return the following object:
{
 "1": {
  "Name": "John"
 },
 "2": {
  "Name": "Darryl"
 }
}

Comment: Yes I just tried this way and it **worked**! :) I didn't realise the dictionary key couldn't be an integer when it's serialized. Thank you so much.